# Android Flavors not finding main activity

Tags: java, android, android-productflavors

Hey guys I am running into a snag with flavors I keep running into issues with the launcher activity for free and paid versions of the app. If I add a specific launcher activity for both I get an error, however if I do the regular auto resolve I get a crash. What should the manifest look like in this case ?? ( I have a separate free and paid version of main in there own specific paid/free directories. Any help is appreciated !

> free > java > com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.free > Main Activity.
>
> main > java > com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger
>
> paid> java > com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.paid> Main Activity.

Manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger" >

    <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">

        <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.udacity.builditbigger.paid.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

** App.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'debug'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/Douglas/.android/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId = "com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.free"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
        }
        paid {
            applicationId = "com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.paid"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':laughlib')
    compile project(':jokeview')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: post your app.gradle

Comment: I dont think you dont need to set the path of your "free" or "paid" directory within the manifest each time you run them. What you need to do is just change the build variantwhich is located in the `bottom right` called `build variant`

Comment: When i set it to just main activity, I receive  Default Activity not foundWaiting for process. As there is no Main activity in the main directory.

Comment: You should have 3 versions of AndroidManifest.xml: the default one, one for paid, and one for free version, show them here as well

Comment: Just added the new manifest versions and it is working, I thought I tried this but probably messed it up. Thanks so much ! :)